# Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial ch 8.3 | Not sure why this test is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to test logging in and out in this RoR app. My test is this:

```
test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
  get login_path
  post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
  assert is_logged_in?
  assert_redirected_to @user
  follow_redirect!
  assert_template 'users/show'
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
  delete logout_path
  assert_redirected_to root_url
  assert_not is_logged_in? # <-- this line is the one that cocks up.
  follow_redirect!
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
end
```

The labelled line is the only line that fails, and I'm not sure why. It's exactly the same as in the book itself.

Sending a delete request to the logout path routes to this function:

```
def destroy
  logout
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

The logout function is this:

```
def logout
  session.delete(:user_id)
  @current_user = nil
end
```

And the is_logged_in? function is this:

```
def is_logged_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

All 3 of those are exactly the way the book said they should be, down to the names. (I did have my own better names, but I changed them out of desperation.)

The site appears to work just fine. [Here's](https://evening-everglades-64700.herokuapp.com/) a link so you can see for yourself. I can log in and out just fine.

I've used assert_not elsewhere and it's worked just fine. For example:

```
test "login with invalid information" do
  get login_path
  assert_template 'sessions/new'
  post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
  assert_template 'sessions/new'
  assert_not flash.empty?
  get root_path
  assert flash.empty?
end
```

This test succeeds. ('Flash' refers to a little box at the top of the page that tells the user, in this case, that their sign-in information was invalid.)

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far in the tutorial, you should have used sessions, and I can see you deleting a session in your `logout` method.

Also, "helper methods aren't available in tests, we can't use the `current_user` as in Listing 8.15, but the `session` method is available"

Your `is_logged_in?` method should look like this then:

```
def is logged_in?
  !session[:user_id].nil?
end
```

Comment: ok well I tried it your way and it works fine now. Thank you veeeeery much!

Comment: @LlamaTarianism yup no problem :)